# How JVM allows debugging of kernel threads?

Tags: multithreading, jvm, internals

I understand that *.class* files contain line numbers associated to the byte code in order to facilitate the job of debuggers as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12).

I also understand that each thread has its own *pc Register* which points at the next instruction, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.1). By using these registers, debuggers are able to, for instance, stop at specific lines, by associating the instruction to the line number.

I also understand that Java threads are bound to OS threads, which are executed as native code.

However, the description of *pc Registers* says that

> If the method currently being executed by the thread is native, the value of the Java Virtual Machine's pc register is undefined.

The question then is: if debuggers use line numbers associated with byte code instructions, and *pc registers* inform the next instruction, how is it possible (in case it actually is) to debug thread code if it is executed as native code and because of that *pc registers* values are undefined?

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I think that the paragraph you quoted is about `native` methods, whose implementation is not managed by JVM (because it is written in some other language) and is not subject to Java debugger. Do not confuse "native method" with "native thread".

Comment: @DanilaKiver, but then how can a native thread execute a code that is non-native, i.e. JVM bytecode? Also, doesn't a native thread run native code?

Comment: The interpreter *is* native code. Also, the JIT compiler produces native code, but code which it can retrace to its originating bytecode (in most cases). When not executing methods declared `native`, the native threads execute either, the interpreter code or JIT compiled code.